# How to find & replace pattern WITHIN specific pattern using sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

IT seems that 'sed' and I will never be friends...

How can I find and replace a pattern within a range (within another pattern)?

In words:
Find: `AllowOverride None` within the following range and replace it with `AllowOverride All`

```
...
<Directory "/var/www/html">
some text
more text
some comments
AllowOverride None
more text
</Directory>
...
```

Please note (if not already done): This is related to httpd.conf which contains a lot more "modules" all ending with `</Directory>`

As this command is used within a yaml file, it would be aesome to achieve this with a one-liner (I am aware, that one-liners are getting ugly pretty fast...).

Also: I rely on using sed (requirement, dont ask me why - pls :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -i -e '/<Directory "\/var\/www\/html">/,/<\/Directory>/{s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/}' filename
```

Comment: It makes so much sense looking at it now. Thank you!